# Install "scratch" library from github

Tags: python

I'm trying to clone something from github (https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch).

Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNjXL9KbN4w) I did on anaconda prompt:

```
git clone https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch.git
```

It worked but when I try to import something, e.g. `from scratch.linear_algebra import dot` I get the error

> No module named 'scratch'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not related to Git. It's just how Python works.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to go  to the correct path (which was not inside the anaconda directory)

(in jupyter): `cd C:\Users\frdei\data-science-from-scratch`

So, I became able to import the module `from scratch.linear_algebra import dot`